# Message argument isn't changing how many times the loop is executed

Tags: java

I have written a method called "car" which moves the car forwards 100 times using a for loop which works fine when tested.

```
public void car(int move)
{  
  for (i = 0; i < move; i++){
  move = 100;

  REST OF CODE NOT RELEVANT
```

I would now like to use this method to write a second method which takes the users input and moves the car forwards the number that they have entered, but I can't figure out the code to do this. Below is what I have added so far:

```
public void move2()   {
      
  int moveCar;

  String moveCarString;

  moveCarString = JOptionPane.inputDialog("Enter the number you would like the car to move forwards by");

  moveCar = Integer.parseInt (moveCarString);
        
      if (move>2000) {
         this.move(moveCar);
```

This displays a dialog box which a user is able to enter information into, but the car moves forwards 100 times like in the loop in move and not by how many times the user has entered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: You need to do for(int i=0; i<move; i++) {...do what you want to do with i}

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions, as it invalidates existing answers; I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 3):

The `car` method currently ignores the value of `move` passed to it. Instead of using it as a loop index, you should introduce a new loop index, and use `move` as the end condition of the loop:

```java
public void car(int move) {
  for (int i = 0; i < move; i++) { // Here
      // Loop's body...
```

Comment: @lilly_brown027 you could pass `100` to it, or overload it with another method that doesn't take an argument and passes `100` to this one